# Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance - Using Camera with OverlayView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I'm having some trouble using the Camera with a custom overlay view.

This is the ViewController I use to set up and present the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CameraOverlayDelegate {

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func pickImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

        let myCameraOverlayViewController = CameraOverlayViewController(
            nibName:"CameraOverlayView",
            bundle: nil)
        let customView = myCameraOverlayViewController.view
        customView.frame = imagePicker.view.frame
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = customView

        myCameraOverlayViewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("No camera")
    }
}

func didTakePhoto(sender: CameraOverlayViewController) {
    print("Do something ...")
}
```

The custom overlay view is a *.xib-file and this is the CameraOverlayViewController I use:

```
import UIKit

protocol CameraOverlayDelegate {
    func didTakePhoto(sender: CameraOverlayViewController)
}

class CameraOverlayViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: CameraOverlayDelegate! = nil

    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

    @IBAction func takePhotoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate.didTakePhoto(self)
    }
}
```

When I run the app I get an error (`-[UIView takePictureButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`) as soon as I click the button which should call the `takePhotoButton(...)`-function.

I'm pretty new to Xcode, iOS developing and Swift ... in case the problem is obviously. ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection between the `UIButton` and the `@IBAction func takePhotoButton` was broken. I fixed it by deleting the whole `CameraOverlayViewController` and making a new one.

There would have been probably an easier way, but I haven't figured out yet how everything is working together in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that you are calling the method on the wrong object. Basically whenever you encounter `unrecognized selector...` it means that you have a problem inside the parenthesis.

`takePhotoButton()` has a sender of type `AnyObject`, but it calls `didTakePhoto()` which has a sender of type `CameraOverlayViewController`. So a button calls a method which should be called by a view controller. Now you see the discrepancy?

Fixing it... I can't help you with that. Maybe somebody else can. As I said above, the same object must call both of your methods. Or maybe you didn't assign something properly in the Storyboard.

Comment: As Lawrence wrote, "you are calling the method on the wrong object", [UIView takePictureButton:] means than takePictureButton method calls on instance of UIView class(maybe it is myView?), that should be wrong, since it should calls on UIButton instance, check your connection in IB(Right click on Files Owner and your UIButton), I believe the reason is somewhere there..